# How to check if given array contains any value from another array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Guys please help me figure out with php. In JS i know that i can use `.some` or `.includes`, but what is analog of doing it in PHP? I read the docs of php, they are very poor about functions for arrays.

I need to solve next problem:

```
['banana', 'apple', 'coconut']
```

i want to return true, if in array above contains any of values from this array `['apple']`, **order of elements in given array must not matter!**

How to solve this problem in php?

Answer (score 2):

I truly don't feel like `PHP` documentation is poor when it comes to `array` functions. In fact the `array_interesect` [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is the first Google result for "check if array contains any element of array".

```
$array_1 = ['banana', 'apple', 'coconut'];
$array_2 = ['banana'];

if (sizeof(array_intersect($array_1, $array_2))) {
    echo "Contains at least 1 element";
} else {
    echo "Doesn't contain even 1 element";
}
```

Comment: You earned the reputation to [flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). Please use this privilege on clear duplicate questions such as this one. Basic functionalities such as this one have about 99,99% chance to have already been convered on the site.